# Texture from World Machine does not render correctly in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, textures

I am having a texture issue that has me stumped.

I'm building an OpenGL renderer with which I've loaded and rendered several models and textures from multiple sources.... all worked as expected. Then I generated a terrain using [WorldMachine](https://www.world-machine.com/). I exported an OBJ with a diffuse texture. For some reason that world machine generated texture renders incorrectly. This is what its supposed to look like.

[image]

When I load it onto it's model in my renderer it looks like this:

[image]

Stealing a texture from another model that's loading and rendering correctly and applying it to this terrain model it looks like it renders correctly.

[image]

I'm using [stb image loader](https://github.com/nothings/stb). The terrain texture seems to load correctly. STB reports that both have 3 channels....

I'm at a loss. It seems like its an issue with the texture its self but I have no idea what it could be. The terrain texture is 1025x1025, the one that works is 4096x4096. Reading [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/NPOT_Texture) confirms that modern hardware shouldn't have issues with non power of two textures so I don't think that's it. I don't know a huge amount about texture formats (jpg/png) is there some rgb ordering or bit size considerations that I need to be aware of?

Does anyone know why this might happen?

Comment: Your 1025x1025 texture stride is not divisible by 4, whereas 4096x4096 is. You need to set `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to `1` as described in the linked question.

Comment: Ah, interesting reading. I wasn't aware of the required channels param in stbi_load. I tried setting it to 4 then set my glTexImage2D formats both to RGBA and it worked! Thank you. If you want to summarize any of this into an answer I will mark it as accepted.